# How to install Trimaran on 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, package-management, software-installation

I am not able to install the `trimaran` package on Ubuntu 12.10. I have tried [this how-to guide](http://akashrishimittal.blogspot.in/2011/10/how-to-install-trimaran-on-ubuntu-1010.html).

Can someone help me find the solution to this problem?

Comment: Please provide a step-by-step protocol of what you did and what the computer prompts.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

When installing such application, its better to **Visit the application website** and get proper instrucions. So its better you to visit [www.trimaran.org](http://www.trimaran.org/download.shtml) and **Read the software requirements** and **Follow the installation manual**