# "declaration is incompatible with "int getnameinfo(..." while installing Trimaran

Tags: 12.04, package-management, software-installation, compiling

I'm having the same issue as posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207086/how-to-install-trimaran-on-12-10), but in my case, using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Live USB, inside `~/trimaran/openimpact` folder.

I try to execute `./install_openimpact`, then the shell replies me at the end:

```
Processing platform/x86lin_gcc/IPA_lib/__impact_lib.c
gcc -w -E -m32 -DIMPACT_FIX -I/home/ubuntu/trimaran/openimpact/platform/x86lin_gcc/include -I/home/ubuntu/trimaran/openimpact/include -I/home/ubuntu/trimaran/openimpact/config/x86lin_c platform/x86lin_gcc/IPA_lib/__impact_lib.c > platform/x86lin_gcc/IPA_lib/__impact_lib.i
impact-edgcpfe --pcode -m -w platform/x86lin_gcc/IPA_lib/__impact_lib.i
"platform/x86lin_gcc/IPA_lib/__impact_lib.c", line 1943: error: declaration is
          incompatible with "int getnameinfo(const struct sockaddr
          *__restrict__, socklen_t, char *__restrict__, socklen_t, char
          *__restrict__, socklen_t, int)" (declared at line 679 of
          "/usr/include/netdb.h")
  int getnameinfo(const struct sockaddr *sa, socklen_t salen, char *host,
      ^

1 error detected in the compilation of "platform/x86lin_gcc/IPA_lib/__impact_lib.i".
Exiting: non-zero exit code
make[1]: *** [platform/x86lin_gcc/IPA_lib/__impact_lib.pst] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/trimaran/openimpact'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file `platform/x86lin_gcc/IPA_lib/__impact_lib.c` and go to line NO: 1943 
then in the function `getnameinfo( )` change the last parameter from  `unsigned int flags` to only  `int flags`  then try installing and the software `openimpact` will install successfully.

Comment: Hey that worked! Thanks a lot for the tip. But I will add some more details in case some other person comes to this thread:
1) automake, tcl, tk and graphviz are available via apt-get, but autoconf should be downloaded and installed.
2) automake should be removed, then version 1.7 installed.
3) lib.c is actually inside on trimaran/platform/ and should have the same modification as you cited previously.